# Key Length & Hashing

Tags: hash, keys, key-derivation

I need to use a hash function to generate a 128-bit key for a symmetric cipher. The specific cipher is from the eStream portofolio, called [Rabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_%28cipher%29).

I am using the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) protocol for authentication (a type of [EKE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encrypted_key_exchange) protocol). As a result of this, both parties will calculate the same large integer value and need to hash it into a key they can both use.

I would like to use [SHA256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) to generate the key, but its output is twice the length required.

Can I just truncate the hash to the lower 128 bits or something?

What is usually done in this case?

Comment: I've just seen another poster ask about the RIPEMD hash functions - I believe there is a 128-bit version. Would anyone recommend using this instead of a SHA2 function in this case? :)

Comment: Why not just use a PRNG?

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer:** just truncate, it's fine.

**Long answer:** you want a [Key Derivation Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function). A KDF turns an arbitrary-sized input (the shared secret obtained from SRP) into a configurable sequence of bytes, which you can split into as many sub-sequences as you need for symmetric cryptography. For instance, [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) defines a KDF (it calls it "PRF"; see section 5) so that it can extend the "master secret" (the shared secret obtained from whatever key exchange mechanism has been used) into *six* elements (an encryption key, a MAC key, and an IV, for each tunnel direction).

If you have a "reasonable" hash function such as SHA-256, and your secret data needs an amount of at most the hash output length, then a simple truncation will be an appropriate KDF. (Theoretically, being a good KDF after truncation is not *implied* by the hash function being appropriately resistant to collisions and preimages, but in practice you will not get any trouble with SHA-256 or SHA-512.)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at PKCS#5 (aka [RFC2898](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt)). Many frameworks (e.g. .NET) will provide you with the classes to use them (prefer the later, v2, one if available).